# Install octomap_server on hydro

Tags: octomap, octomap-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys, following the guide in http://answers.ros.org/question/91111/rgbdslam-in-ros-hydro/ and http://answers.ros.org/question/105871/rgbd-in-hydro/, I am trying to install RGBD SLAM package on Hydro. When I install octomap_server on http://wiki.ros.org/octomap_mapping some thing wrong happens.

I run sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-octomap ros-hydro-octomap-mapping, I do not "add the source directory to your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH (e.g. in ~/.bashrc), source that file", because I do not know how to source it and do not know where is it.
Then rosdep install octomap_mapping, it shows that #All required rosdeps installed successfully.
There is some strange when I rosmake octomap_mapping. It says that
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['octomap_mapping']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/rical/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140326-225216
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['octomap_mapping'] to:
[]
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The stack "catkin" was not found. We will assume it is using the new buildsystem and try to continue...
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The stack "octomap_server" was not found. We will assume it is using the new buildsystem and try to continue...
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 0 packages with 0 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/rical/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140326-225216

As a beginner, I would like to ask how to fix this problem? Do I need to download the source to a catkin workspace and then catkin_make? Or, what to do to install it successfully? Many thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/145061/install-octomap_server-on-hydro/) by [pinocchio](https://answers.ros.org/users/13681/pinocchio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2014-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guessed that you tried to install packages of both "octomap" and "octomap_mapping" with apt-get.
After I also tried it, I checked if their package was installed. So, there were their packages in /opt/ros/hydro/share/.
Why do you try rosmake? Do you want to edit the source in the paskages?
When I checked on http://wiki.ros.org/octomap_mapping, the web explained that To compile the stack from source needed rosmake on fuerte. Actually, in the case of hydro, you will need catkin_make, because CMakeLists.txt describes find_package(catkin REQUIRED). A detail explanation of catkin_ws and catkin_make is described on the web http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/using_a_workspace.

---

Originally posted by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) with karma: 894 on 2014-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pinocchio](https://answers.ros.org/users/13681/pinocchio/) on 2014-03-27**:
Hi @Ken_in_JAPAN, I think I make a silly mistake. I just need to "sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-octomap ros-hydro-octomap-mapping" to install octomap_server, right? Many thanks.

**Comment by [Ken_in_JAPAN](https://answers.ros.org/users/11311/ken_in_japan/) on 2014-03-27**:
I think you are right, because octomap_mapping includes octomap_server. See you!

**Comment by [pinocchio](https://answers.ros.org/users/13681/pinocchio/) on 2014-03-27**:
Thank you @Ken_in_JAPAN